# Force unhealthy instance for rolling code updates?

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I'm looking into Google Compute's load balancing and need to figure out a way to efficiently do a code roll. I tried making our app respond with a `500` status code but the pool still reports the instance as "Healthy". Below is the configuration:

**HTTP Health Check**
The `request-path` returns "UP" if our CPU/Memory usage is not above a threshold. I tried making this path return a `500` HTTP status code which simply outputs "500" to the page with the correct status code header.

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+------+------------------+
| name              | description | host | port | request-path     |
+-------------------+-------------+------+------+------------------+
| lb-usc1-app-check |             |      | 8888 | /monitoring/si4g |
+-------------------+-------------+------+------+------------------+
```

**Target Pool (Contains 6 instances)**

```
+------------------+-------------+-------------+
| name             | description | region      |
+------------------+-------------+-------------+
| lb-usc1-app-pool |             | us-central1 |
+------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Forwarding Rules**

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| name            | description | region      | ip            | protocol | port-range | target                                   |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| lb-usc1-app-443 |             | us-central1 | 23.236.56.210 | TCP      | 443-443    | us-central1/targetPools/lb-usc1-app-pool |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| lb-usc1-app-80  |             | us-central1 | 23.236.56.210 | TCP      | 80-80      | us-central1/targetPools/lb-usc1-app-pool |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
```

**Further Details**
However, it appears that if I run `service nginx stop` the instance will report as down. But this is obviously not the right answer as I need to report the current instance being deployed to as unhealthy, wait for all connections to finish, and then deploy our code.

Also, if it matters, my "Session Affinity" on the pool is set to "None".

So, in short, what is the best way to force the GE Load Balancer to see the instance as "unhealthy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears all that was needed was to set the status code to 503 and it started working.